# How to determine if a NET Core class library is running in the context of a desktop or web application

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, cross-platform

I  have a .NET Core class library that provides functionality which can be used both by desktop and web applications. I would like to support as many of the platforms supported by .NET Core as possible.

When running in the context of a web application, I want the library to be able to detect the domain on which the application is hosted. Normally, I would do this using the `HttpContext.Request` object, making the context available by injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`. However, a desktop application has no `HttpContext`.

Is there any way of injecting a service so that the reference is null in the consumer when it cannot be supplied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, in dependency injection configuration, I tested to see if the default AspNet Core `HttpContextAccessor` was present, and if not, I pass in a fake object with a null HttpContext.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    var accessorType = GetAccessorType() ?? typeof(NullOpHttpAccessor);
    services.TryAddSingleton(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor), accessorType);
    ...
}

private static Type GetAccessorType()
{
    var interfaceType = typeof(IHttpContextAccessor);
    var excludedNames = new[] { "IHttpContextAccessor", "NullOpHttpAccessor" };
    var type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .FirstOrDefault(t => !excludedNames.Contains(t.Name) &&
                             interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
    return type;
}

internal class NullOpHttpAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
{
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get => null; set => value = null; }
}
```

Then, in my library, I inject `HttpContextAccessor`, test to see if the context is null, and proceed accordingly.

```
internal string DoStuff()
{
    if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null)
    {
        return GetMacAddress();
    }
    return HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application is used by desktop application it will be impossible to use HttpContext as you do with Web applications when a request comes in, so we need a work around.

Given that you follow naming conventions in your applications, I would suggest to use Reflection and read the application name

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In the scenario that I am considering, however, I won't know the names of assemblies that use the library, so this approach won't work.